# How to think of states when designing a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, theory

I am learning about designing Turing machines and I am struggling when it comes to creating the states diagram, for example if I wanted to design a Turing machine of the language $L=\{a^nb^n, n\geq 0\}$, here its state diagram:
[image]
I understand the concept behind the solution, i.e: replacing the first with a with an X then matching it with a B (if it exists) which will be replaced by Y and doing this again and again, however, when I it comes to designing the states diagram I am completely lost. Namely, what is the role of each state? How do we know how many states should we have? How do we know this should be a new state instead of the same one?